# Bootstrap grid in wordpress theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, bootstrap-4

I hope everyone is having fun. 
I have yet another stupid question! I'm trying to add sidebar widget to my Wordpress website but when I try to include get_sidebar(); it appears above my products section. I would like it to appear on the right or left side of my products section.

I looked into some similar situations explained in this website but it seems I'm missing something.

this is my page: https://ilens-gallery.com

here is the code for products section:
https://codeshare.io/24APK3

I tried to change bootsrap settings by adding

```
echo '<div class="row">';
echo '<div class="col-sm-6  col-sm-offset-3">';
get_sidebar();
```

and this gives me widget on top not on the side. Please guide me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: you didnt include get_sidebar() in your code?

Comment: Is the sidebar the part with the banners?

Comment: You need to incorporate that in your existing grid. It would mean changing some other grid sizes here and there. Also, code belongs **within the question itself** and the code needs to be minimal complete and verifiable.